# Simulator not showing any output

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, xcode9.4

when I integrate cocoapods I'm getting an error in the simulator. Although my simulator is working when I work without integrating cocoapods..when I run my code on the simulator, it is not showing any output, this is the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Vf1.png)of the simulator as well as breakpoint [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psn0A.png)

```
AppDelegate.swift

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("gasdgsdsjbnksdfkdf")
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("shgdsgfskdakdjadj")

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        if let window = self.window {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            let nav = UINavigationController()
            let mainView = ViewController()
            nav.viewControllers = [mainView]
            window.rootViewController = nav
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
       }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: what result you expecting? your view controller is displaying as show in pic. What error you are getting in simulator

Comment: I'm expecting Login screen..which is my initial viewController  but I'm getting this blank white view

Comment: what does `ViewController` have? what screen is that?

Comment: it is a simple Login screen, after successful login, it will redirect to home screen which contain google map integration

Comment: If you want to start view programmatically  try remove story board name from main interface in `target -> project -> general -> (scroll down to main interface ) -> remove Main text` .

Answer (score 0):

```
let mainView = ViewController()
```

This is not the proper way to initialise your view controller from storyboard.

Use

```
UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "<"Your storyboard id">") as? ViewController
```